# Can I use the font Collegiate FLF for commercial use without legal consequences?

Tags: intellectual-property, internet, licensing

I would like to use the typeface Collegiate FLF, the designers went out of business back in 2003 - Casady-Greene

I have been searching for a commercial license for this typeface to no avail. I am not able to find somewhere to purchase it.

I did find a website stating the history and closure of of the Casady-Greene business that closed in 2003 and the rights may have been given to the 'MAC' platform...

Thank you for your time.

Comment: In what jurisdiction? One of the areas of greatest variation in copyright law is how "orphan copyrights" are handled.

Comment: I don't follow ... Who would I pay? I have searched for the license ....

Comment: I reside in Canada ...

Comment: You didn't ask "is it legal" - the answer would be "no". You asked "can I do it without legal consequences" - the answer is "quite likely if nobody is selling this font, but no guarantees".

Comment: I don't mind paying for commercial use, but who do I pay?

Comment: I found out that the font was available on windows 7 and macOS. If so, would it be available free for commercial use?